# Is it a must to install appmor or Selinux a like to run debian server to host wordpress?

Tags: debian, wordpress

I am interested in debian server, but Centos 7 has SElinux. Do I need SElinux a like for debian server to host a wordpress?

Thanks

Comment: I can't answer if it's required or not. But I can say that it would be a good idea to learn how to make use of SElinux to enhance your system security and use it if you're going to have your computer the network.

Comment: I want to install 1 blog on 1 ip kvm vps. I am wondering if I need SElinux or appmor to secure my site and the vps. If the not having Selinux and appmor is secure enough, I like not to have one of them.

Comment: Many distributions install them automatically. While it's better to know how to configure the stuff and have it configured as specifically as feasible for your situation, using one of these distributions and just not fighting its SElinux and apparmor configurations is almost certainly better than not having them. I didn't talk much about apparmor before because I haven't actually had any clear need to mess with it, but it's on all of the Linux servers I run, along with SElinux. Living with preinstalled SElinux is mostly just knowing to do ls -lZ to check assignments and chcon to fix things.

Comment: audit2why is also useful to get an explanation of why things didn't work, but the vast majority of the time, I find I can just list the directory with the inaccessible file using the ls -lZ options I mentioned and comparing the inaccessible file's settings to the accessible files beside it.

Answer (score 1):

AppArmor and SELinux are not required to host Wordpress on a server. They are recommended though if available in your distro. SELinux and AppArmor may be enabled by default in your distro of choice, though they can be disabled. I would recommend instead setting the context of your Wordpress files appropriately.

To disable SELinux or AppArmor:

- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/
- https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse#Disable_AppArmor

Alternatively, if SELinux gives you trouble, restore the context of /var/www/html after adding files:

- https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-65817443e1aad7a1d1c87f6a4dc73a964b38224b